# How do I know if I can replace the 27 inch wheels with 700c wheels on my MIELE bike?

Tags: wheels

I need a help with choosing a wheelset for my Miele bike.I can't fully understand if it is possible to replace my old rigida 27 inch wheels for 700c coz i have too little free place.I visited a site where there is a size table of wheels and saw that it is possible(judging by numbers).There are no 27 inch wheels in my country at all,so im made to think of whether to  put 26" or if possible 700c.[image]

Answer (score 3):

There a lot of charts posted on the internet explaining the complex data of bicycle wheel sizing. In your case you likely have standard 27 inch wheels that equate to a 630mm iso wheel. A 700c wheel is iso size 622mm, slightly shorter than your current wheel. The primary concern is if your brake pads can move close enough toward the axle to contact the brake surface of the wheel. Then you need to match the axle mounting type, basically bolt-on or quick release. Then comes hub width. Ideally you would like to match your old one however there are articles about drop out spreading on steel framed bikes. Definitely not recommended for aluminum or carbon frames.

Comment: So,as i understood it is possible if my brake pads will fit the rim?But how is 27 inch wheel bigger than 28, or these "inches" are very relative and all depends from tire?

Comment: The inches were measured with different tyres, including the tyre. Always go for ISO sizes when uncertain. They measure hub to rim, and are independent of what tyres people used a century ago.

Comment: Or so all depends from my tire.Teoritecally I can put 28inch wheel with a kind of tire to fit my frame place?

Comment: Yes, but along with brake issue you must also meet the other criteria,.The confusion was due to the  lack of a standard universal point of measurement. Yes 27 inch wheels are larger than 700c.

Comment: Which criteria?

Comment: Hub width, axle type bolt on or quick release

Comment: @Nikita - A 27-inch tire fits a larger diameter rim than a 28-inch tire.  Tire sizes (other than ISO) make no sense.

Comment: Adding to the nonsense of tire sizes, some tires marked the same size are different diameters, e.g. there are 4 different Iso wheel sizes for 26" tires and two of those are 26x1 3/8 -  https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tyre-sizing.html

Comment: You can switch between normal quick release and bolt axle without problems. It's through axle that is different and they were popularised in 2010s.

Comment: I have had issues getting a quick-release tight enough on some horizontal drop outs. High loads cause the wheel to torque over  and become misaligned.

Comment: guys if i buy 700c rim (dp 18 weinmann).I can put any tire for 700c that will fit my frame?so its like universal?